# jinja2 loop over a dictionary and get values of an multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, jinja2

My dictionary:

```
ipsec_credentials:
  usernames:
    - user1
    - user2
  passwords:
    - pass1
    - pass2
```

I have a dictionary that contains "usernames" and "passwords" as keys and each of this keys has an array as a value. I want to iterate over this dictionary to get as a result

```
user1 : pass1
user2 : pass2
```

I am really not able to figure this out in jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use indexing instead of generic iteration. Look:

```
{% set passwords = ipsec_credentials.passwords %}
{% set usernames = ipsec_credentials.usernames %}
{% for i in range(passwords | length) %}
   {{ usernames[i] }} : {{ passwords[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here we take usernames and passwords into separate variables and then index this variables via common index. As a result we iterate both arrays simultaneously.